# printf causes code crash

Tags: c, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I am working on MODBUS creating library. Library is working fine for testing purpose I am using a Modbus based Power meter. I am facing a very strange problem. 
Trying to print value on console, by using printf. By fetching first value side by side I am printing it, on second fetch value is coming in array correctly but on using pritnf code get crashed. :( 
I have tried to debug the code also and came to know on using printf for a value second time code get crashed.

Here is part of code:

```
int wmain(void)
{
    FLOAT dataFloat[5] = {0};
    CHAR dataBuffer[200] = {0};
    // Initializing Structure declared in library header
    psModbusRTU pModbus =(psModbusRTU)malloc(sizeof(psModbusRTU)); 

    // Array pointer to store data
    BYTE *readData = (BYTE *) malloc(NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS * sizeof(BYTE));
    memset(readData, 0, NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS * sizeof(BYTE));   

    // Function to read the voltage
    if (!ModbusRTUReadRegister(pModbus, FC_READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, VOLTAGE_REGISTER_ADDRESS, NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS, readData))
    {
        printf("\nERROR Read register error %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    dataFloat[0] = hexToFloatPointConversion(readData);
    printf("\nvoltage : %f", dataFloat[0]);  //(THIS IS FIRST PRINTF TILL HERE CODE IS FINE)

    /// Function reads the frequnecy
    if (!ModbusRTUReadRegister(pModbus, FC_READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS, FREQUENCY_REGISTER_ADDRESS, NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS, readData))
    {
        printf("\nERROR Read register error %d", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }
    dataFloat[1] = hexToFloatPointConversion(readData); // Saving frequency value in array
    printf("\nFrequency : %f", dataFloat[1]); // (THIS IS WHERE PROBLEM ARISES CODE CRASH WITH NO REASON)
```

hexToFloatPointConversion Function:

```
FLOAT hexToFloatPointConversion(BYTE *readData)
{
    DWORD dataHex = 0;
    DWORD exponent = 0;
    DWORD fraction = 0;
    DWORD signBit = 0;
    FLOAT dataFloat = 0;

    /// Saving BYTE array data into one DWORD
    dataHex = readData[0];
    dataHex = dataHex << 8;
    dataHex = dataHex + readData[1];
    dataHex = dataHex << 8;
    dataHex = dataHex + readData[2];
    dataHex = dataHex << 8;
    dataHex = dataHex + readData[3];    

    /// Getting sign bit, exponent and fraction
    signBit = dataHex >> 31;
    exponent = (dataHex >> 23 & 0xFF);
    fraction = dataHex & 0x7FFFFF;

    /// Calculation for converting data into float.
    dataFloat = (pow(2, (exponent - SINGLE_PRECISION_CONSTANT)) * ( 1 + (fraction * pow(2, -23))));

    return dataFloat;
}
```

psModbusRTU structure:

```
typedef struct sModbusRTU
{   
    HANDLE  hModbus; 
    BYTE    slaveNumber;
    BYTE    functionCode;           
    BOOL    fModbusInitialize;
    BOOL    fSlaveAddress;   
    BOOL    fModbusOpen;
    BOOL    fException; 
    WCHAR   portName[16];
    DWORD   exceptionData;
    DCB     dcb;
}sModbusRTU, *psModbusRTU;
```

Tried to debug also in run time and looked into dis-assembly break point but did not get exactly why it is happening.
Here is the dis-assembly:

```
40050658  str         r3, [sp, #0x14] 
4005065C  str         r5, [sp, #8] 
40050660  str         r2, [sp] 
40050664  str         r4, [sp, #4] 
40050668  bl          40031078 
4005066C  __debugbreak_ce         //Break point
40050670  mvn         r3, #0x37, 24 
40050674  eor         r3, r3, #0xAB 
40050678  ldr         r2, [r3] 
4005067C  movw        r3, #0xF7F8 
40050680  movt        r3, #0xF101
```

Please help me out, my project is stuck in middle just because of this small problem. 
Please respond back soon

Comment: Are you checking your "readData" after second call, if it contains the valid data or not. And what would you return if "hexToFloatPointConversion" fails?

Comment: Problem might be around `hexToFloatPointConversion(readData)`, can we see the function ?

Comment: Are you sure you `malloc` enough memory? Single register is 2 bytes in Modbus. Maybe you should do `BYTE *readData =  malloc(NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS * 2);` assuming that `sizeof(BYTE) == sizeof(char)` (== 1).

Comment: How is FLOAT `typedef`ed?

Comment: @Abhineet: Yes, I checked data after second call during run time debugging data is coming correctly in readData, moreover in dataFloat[1] after calling hexToFloatPointConversion(readData) data is correct but when I use pritnf code get crashed.

Comment: @Gabson hexToFloatPointConversion(readData) return float value sure I will post that function too. Please look into the original post have pasted hexToFloatPointConversion(readData)

Comment: @user694733 Yes I am sure I have enough memory, its in GB

Comment: @Bit Fiddling Code Monkey : FLOAT typedef is float

Comment: Can you try making "dataFloat" as "DOUBLE" ?

Comment: @Abhineet Yes, just tried after ur suggestion, no success. Strange thing is I took a random integer type  variable and assigned value to it. Even if I print varible value just after printf for voltage (first printf) code crashed

Comment: @Rajat I didn't mean if *your computer* has enough memory. I meant that you maybe allocate too little memory for `readData`. In Modbus one register is 2 bytes, so you should allocate twice the size for them (`NUMBER_OF_READ_REGISTERS * 2`).

Comment: @user694733 Yes u are right I multiplied it with 2 but no success

Answer (score 1):

Wrong size passed to `malloc()`.

```
// was psModbusRTU pModbus =(psModbusRTU)malloc(sizeof(psModbusRTU));
// -----------------------------------------------v--------------
psModbusRTU pModbus = (psModbusRTU) malloc(sizeof(*psModbusRTU));
```

---

Suggest alternate `malloc()` idiom.  Use `sizeof(*target)`.
Also, unless you compiler *requires* it (which it shouldn't), recommend dropping the cast

```
// example
psModbusRTU *pModbus = malloc(sizeof(*pModbus));
```

Comment: psModbusRTU  is pointer to structure

I dropped casting also but no success

Comment: @Rajat did you add the `*` to `psModbusRTU pModbus = (psModbusRTU) malloc(sizeof(*psModbusRTU));`?

Comment: Yes i tried, getting error ''malloc' : too few arguments for call' I think it means compeler need casting

Comment: @Rajat We getting stuck on the casting issue.  Set the casting issue aside.  The _size_ in your post is wrong.  `malloc(sizeof(psModbusRTU))` should be `malloc(sizeof(*psModbusRTU))`. If this still compiles wrong, please show `psModbusRTU` definition and any type it depends on.  TTFN

Comment: I have posted structure in my original post. Please have a look on it. And I am still getting the error.

Comment: 1) Suggest editing your post to show your are now doing `sizeof(*psModbusRTU)` and 2) I think you are corrupting memory _somewhere_.  Maybe in `ModbusRTUReadRegister()`?  I do not think it is a `printf()` issue.

Answer (score 0):

The %f specifier is expecting to format a `double` (8 bytes) and not a `float` (4 bytes) (See [this MSDN page for details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms859597.aspx). Try casting the values to `double` in your `printf` statements, e.g. `printf("\nvoltage : %f", (double) dataFloat[0]);`

Comment: A `float` passed to a [Variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Example_in_C) is automatically promoted to `double`.  This is the default promotion for function parameters with a ... or no prototype  C11dr §6.5.2.2 6.  Using `printf()`, `%f` specifier works for `double` as well as `float`.

Comment: David LaPorte : Thanks for the response, %f is not the problem because, even if I use printf second time just to print a simple integer using %d problem code get crashed